# How to Directly pass parameter to Jenkins Pipeline in shell or powershell files(.sh & .ps1).(Without modifying theirs freestyle configure)

Tags: shell, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am now using **Gitlab** Hook with **Jenkins** and trying to do some automation test on it.
Now my normal working **Build Configure** is like this: (Easy sample)

```
./testps.ps1 Hello Secret
```

> And this is the Powershell code:

```
$hi = "my age is:"
echo "$($args[0])" $hi "$($args[1])"
```

> The build result:

```
Hello
my age is:
Secret
Finished: SUCCESS
```

And so does mostly the same way in building Shell freestyle project.

But now I have to run it on **pipeline**,but it seems to not work in the same way.
here's the way i try(but fail):

```
    node {
        paramAValue = "Hi"
        paramBValue = "Wayne"
        build job: 'Testps', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamA', value: paramAValue], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'ParamB', value: paramBValue]]
    }
```

> > The build result just show **nothing**:(in pipeline)

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Jenkins\workspace\0.Test\scripted pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] build (Building 0.Test » Testps)
Scheduling project: 0.Test » Testps
Starting building: 0.Test » Testps #14
```

(nothing here)

my age is:

(nothing here)

Finished: SUCCESS

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

And also I try something like this:

```
powershell './testps Hi 123'
```

Still not work,apparently I didn't learn it well :(

Is there anyone know how Directly pass parameter into pipeline job??

And this is my first quesion here,if there's anything wrong please tell me:D

Comment: Actually you can ignore the shell part,what I want to say is shell scripts have the same result.

Comment: Have you defined parameters inside your `Testps` job? In `This build is parameterized` option, see [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) document.

Comment: We would really need to see the relevant portion of the `Jenkinsfile` for `Testps` to assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Powershell Params

```
Param ( $age, $secret)
Write-Host $age
```

In the pipeline configure pass

```
"../test.ps1' -age ${paramAValue} -secret ${paramBValue}"
```

Not sure if the exact code works. The basic idea is use pass parameter using -parameterName